# How to temporarily mask a file in a read-only filesystem with another file?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to use a software library to run some computations. These computations can be customized using a few configuration files in its share directory. Unfortunately this library only provides hard coded paths to specific files in its (read-only) share directory which store these default configurations. Thus right now only a super-user or administrator could modify them. The library doesn't search for any user-local versions of these configuration files. I'd like to develop a wrapper tool which additionally takes a path to an alternate version of one of these configuration files in the users home directory and have that file somehow appear to "mask" the original file on the file system for the duration of process execution without actually modifying the original file in any way (since it can't). Is there a Linux tool I could use to do this sort of thing?

Comment: There is `unionfs` and `mergefs` and such, but can't you just allow users to modify the config file? It would be way easier to think with real world examples - where is the config file? What should the result be?

Comment: No, as my use case requires including this as a function in a high level functional language. So, I want this operation to be "stateless" without having to fork the library.

Comment: `stateless` - then I think `chroot` and generate the new config file inside the `chroot`. You could mount with unionfs root directory and your dir with the config and chroot there

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll see if I can make it work. Thanks :)